# How to make a custom TextBoxField with rounded border on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I need make a textboxField on Blackberry with rounded border.
I try make a custom textbox but it seem not good.
Can anybody share me a class for good custom TextBoxField on Blackberry ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
final Bitmap header_Bitmap = //background image;
    VerticalFieldManager vfm_ = new VerticalFieldManager(
            Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR
                    | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL
                    | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setBackgroundColor(0x040811);
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, header_Bitmap.getWidth(),
                    header_Bitmap.getHeight(), header_Bitmap, 0, 0);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };
```

[image]

```
 Bitmap borderBitmap = //the rounded image;
        VerticalFieldManager vfm_email = new VerticalFieldManager();
        vfm_email.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(5, 5,
                5, 5), borderBitmap));
        EmailAddressEditField email = new EmailAddressEditField("Email : ", "", 50, Field.FOCUSABLE);
        vfm_email.add(email);
        vfm_.add(vfm_email);
        add(vfm_);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code what should be written in the commented background image,"img.bmp" as it gives an error
final Bitmap header_Bitmap = "img.bmp" ;//background image;

```
    VerticalFieldManager vfm_ = new VerticalFieldManager(
        Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR
                | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL
                | Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH)
```