# Blackberry Rounded Text Boxes

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Hi i want to create a login form in blackberry,
I have taken the username and password from the user but i want the username and password to appear inside the round rectangular text box.

But I am not able to draw a round rectangle 
Any help?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226600/how-to-make-an-good-custom-textboxfield-on-blackberry

Comment: Help appreciated as I am not able to understand the code

Answer (score 0):

On BBOS 4.6 and later, you can create a `net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Border` object and pass it to a field's `setBorder()` method.  Look at the `net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BorderFactory` class to help you construct `Border` objects, such as with one of its `createRoundedBorder()` methods.